# Google Apps Script validation issue in Google UiApp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, dom-events, google-sites

I have been trying to figure out Google Apps Script validation in Google Sites and have yet to make the validation part work correctly.

**I need to validate 2 things:**

1. That there is at least 5 characters in the "location" textbox (up to 100)
2. That a date has been selected from the dropdown

**If both conditions are not met, then it should make visible 2 things:**

1. warnException
2. warnExceptionMes

That's it.

The rest of my logic is working great. I am just starting out.

The full logic is listed below. I have replaced our domain info with xxxxxxxxx.

So far, it either never shows the messages and does nothing or just getting one of the items right allows it to move forward. They should both meet the requirements or the warnExceptions should be thrown. This would also be the same if a user loaded the page and did not fill either/or area out and just pushed the button.

How can I validate the Location textbox and the dateBox?

```
var templateIDToCopy = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
var folderIDtoCopyTo = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
var councilMembers = ['Unknown','Name 1','Name 2'];

function doGet(e) {
  var text= new Array();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var hpanel = app.createGrid(4, 6).setId('pannel');
  var hpanelException = app.createGrid(2,3).setId('hpanelException');
  var location = app.createTextBox().setName('location').setId("location").setWidth('200');
  var minuteTaker = app.createListBox().setName('minuteTaker').setId("minuteTaker").setWidth('200')
   for (var i = 0 ; i < councilMembers.length; i++) {
    minuteTaker.addItem(councilMembers.valueOf()[i]);
                    }
  
  var dateBox = app.createDateBox().setId('dateBox').setName('dateBox').setFireEventsForInvalid(false);
  var hour = app.createListBox(false).setId('hour').setName('hour')
//  var hour = app.createListBox(false).setId('hour').setName('hour')
  for(h=1;h<13;++h){hour.addItem(h)}
  var min = app.createListBox(false).setId('minute').setName('minute')
  .addItem('00').addItem('15').addItem('30').addItem('45'); 
  var amPm = app.createListBox(false).setId('am').setName('amPm')
  .addItem('AM').addItem('PM');  
  var dateTimeLabel = app.createLabel('',false).setId('dateTimeLabel');
  var submit = app.createButton('Create Minutes').setId('submit').setPixelSize(196, 25);
  var nextSteps = app.createAnchor('Please click here to see the minutes archive.', 'https://drive.google.com/xxxxxxxxxx/folderview?xxxxxxxxxx').setId('nextSteps').setVisible(false);
   
// Setup error message 
  var warnException =app.createImage('https://sites.google.com/xxxxxxxxxx/minutes/create-new-minutes/Opps.png').setId('warnException').setVisible(false);
  var warnExceptionMes = app.createLabel('The date and Location are required. Please try again.').setStyleAttribute('font-weight', 'normal').setStyleAttribute('font-size','14px').setVisible(false);

// handlers
  var handler1 = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateLength(location, 0, 50).validateMatches(dateBox, '2', 'g')
  .forTargets(warnException).setVisible(true)
  .forTargets(warnExceptionMes).setVisible(true);
 
  var handler2 = app.createServerHandler('handlerFunction')
  .validateLength(location, 1, 100).validateNotMatches(dateBox, '2', 'g')
  .addCallbackElement(location).addCallbackElement(dateBox).addCallbackElement(hpanel);
   
  submit.addClickHandler(handler1).addClickHandler(handler2);
   
  hpanel.setWidget(0,0,app.createLabel('Select Date'))
   .setWidget(0,1,app.createLabel('Hour'))
   .setWidget(0,2,app.createLabel('Minutes'))
   .setWidget(0,3,app.createLabel('AM/PM'))
   .setWidget(0,4,app.createLabel('Location'))
   .setWidget(0,5,app.createLabel('Minute Taker'))
   
  hpanel.setWidget(1,0,dateBox)
   .setWidget(1,1,hour)
   .setWidget(1,2,min)
   .setWidget(1,3,amPm)
   .setWidget(1,4,location)
   .setWidget(1,5,minuteTaker)
  
   hpanel.setWidget(2,5,submit)
   app.add(hpanel);//.add(warnException).add(warnExceptionMes);
  
  hpanelException.setWidget(1,1,warnException).setStyleAttribute("text-align", "right")
   .setWidget(1,2,warnExceptionMes)
  // .setWidget(1,2,nextSteps)
   app.add(hpanelException);
   return app;
     }


function handlerFunction(e) {
 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
 app.getElementById('submit').setText('Building, please wait...').setEnabled(false);
   
  var location = e.parameter.location; 
  var determineName = e.parameter.minuteTaker;  
  var date = e.parameter.dateBox;
  var timeZone = date.toString().substr(25,6)+":00";  
  var dateMilli = date.getTime();  
  var hour = parseInt(e.parameter.hour);  
  var amPm = e.parameter.amPm;
  if (amPm == 'PM' && hour != 12) hour = hour + 12;  
  if (hour == 12 && amPm == 'AM') hour = 0;  
  var hourMilli = hour * 3600000;  
  var minMilli = parseInt(e.parameter.minute) * 60000;  
  var milliTotal = dateMilli + hourMilli + minMilli; 

  // create custom format
  var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(milliTotal), timeZone, 'MM/dd/yy hh:mm aaa');
  app.getElementById('dateTimeLabel').setText(newDate);

  // make a copy of the minutes template to use
  var duplicateID = DriveApp.getFileById(templateIDToCopy)
  .makeCopy('Simply Minutes v1.0 - Stage 1: Building new minutes...')
 .getId();

// get the id of the annual folder where minutes will be stored
  var getFolderID = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderIDtoCopyTo);

// copy new minutes sheet to the annual folder where minutes are stored
  var moveIT = DriveApp.getFileById(duplicateID).makeCopy('Simply Minutes v1.0 - Stage 2: Building new minutes...', getFolderID).getId();

// get the new minutes doc that was created
  var template = DocumentApp.openById(moveIT);
  var templateHeader = template.getHeader();
  var templateBody = template.getActiveSection();

// fill in the values
  templateHeader.replaceText("<date>", newDate);
  templateBody.replaceText("<date>", newDate);
  templateHeader.replaceText("<location>", location);
  templateBody.replaceText("<location>", 'N/A');
  var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  var eUser = Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername();
  var createdBy = '';
  
  if(ContactsApp.getContact(email)){     
     var fullName = ContactsApp.getContact(email).getFullName();
     createdBy = fullName;
  }
  else {
     createdBy = 'N/A';
  };
  
  var determineName = e.parameter.minuteTaker;
  templateHeader.replaceText("<minutetaker>", determineName);
  templateHeader.replaceText("<createdby>", createdBy)
  templateBody.replaceText("<minutetaker>", determineName);
  templateBody.replaceText("<createdby>", createdBy); 
  template.setName(newDate + ' TAC Minutes Recorded By ' + determineName);
  
// close out the doc
  template.saveAndClose();
  
  
  // remove the copy that was left in the root directory
 
 //  DriveApp.getFileById(duplicateID).isTrashed();
   DriveApp.getFileById(duplicateID).setTrashed(true);
  
  app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('submit').setText('Completed!').setEnabled(false);
  app.getElementById('nextSteps').setVisible(true);
  return app;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this (see below) I changed a bit the validations and separated in 2 handlers + added a "clear" handler to be able to click-to-delete the warnings... [test code here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxBywFsLpdKU2J03eEw3RRDwteUCW2REpC3YeTQrdnhfbe4qw_E/exec)

You have also to add something to clear the warnings in the server handler and, why not combine the image and text warning in a single widget ? (easier to clean)

code below :

```
function doGet(e) {
  var text= new Array();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var hpanel = app.createGrid(4, 6).setId('pannel');
  var clearHandler = app.createClientHandler().forEventSource().setVisible(false)
  var hpanelException = app.createGrid(2,3).setId('hpanelException');
  var location = app.createTextBox().setName('location').setId("location").setWidth('200');
  var minuteTaker = app.createListBox().setName('minuteTaker').setId("minuteTaker").setWidth('200')
   for (var i = 0 ; i < councilMembers.length; i++) {
    minuteTaker.addItem(councilMembers.valueOf()[i]);
                    }

  var dateBox = app.createDateBox().setId('dateBox').setName('dateBox').setFireEventsForInvalid(false);
  var hour = app.createListBox(false).setId('hour').setName('hour')
//  var hour = app.createListBox(false).setId('hour').setName('hour')
  for(h=1;h<13;++h){hour.addItem(h)}
  var min = app.createListBox(false).setId('minute').setName('minute')
  .addItem('00').addItem('15').addItem('30').addItem('45'); 
  var amPm = app.createListBox(false).setId('am').setName('amPm')
  .addItem('AM').addItem('PM');  
  var dateTimeLabel = app.createLabel('',false).setId('dateTimeLabel');
  var submit = app.createButton('Create Minutes').setId('submit').setPixelSize(196, 25);
  var nextSteps = app.createAnchor('Please click here to see the minutes archive.', 'https://drive.google.com/xxxxxxxxxx/folderview?xxxxxxxxxx').setId('nextSteps').setVisible(false);

// Setup error message 
  var warnException =app.createImage('https://sites.google.com/xxxxxxxxxx/minutes/create-new-minutes/Opps.png').setId('warnException').setVisible(false).addClickHandler(clearHandler);
  var warnExceptionMes = app.createLabel('The date and Location are required. Please try again.').setStyleAttribute('font-weight', 'normal').setStyleAttribute('font-size','14px').setVisible(false).addClickHandler(clearHandler);

// handlers
  var handler0 = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateLength(location, 0, 5)
  .forTargets(warnException).setVisible(true)
  .forTargets(warnExceptionMes).setVisible(true);
  var handler1 = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateNotMatches(dateBox, '2', 'g')
  .forTargets(warnException).setVisible(true)
  .forTargets(warnExceptionMes).setVisible(true);

  var handler2 = app.createServerHandler('handlerFunction')
  .validateLength(location, 6, 100).validateMatches(dateBox, '2', 'g')
  .addCallbackElement(location).addCallbackElement(dateBox).addCallbackElement(hpanel);

  submit.addClickHandler(handler0).addClickHandler(handler1).addClickHandler(handler2);

  hpanel.setWidget(0,0,app.createLabel('Select Date'))
   .setWidget(0,1,app.createLabel('Hour'))
   .setWidget(0,2,app.createLabel('Minutes'))
   .setWidget(0,3,app.createLabel('AM/PM'))
   .setWidget(0,4,app.createLabel('Location'))
   .setWidget(0,5,app.createLabel('Minute Taker'))

  hpanel.setWidget(1,0,dateBox)
   .setWidget(1,1,hour)
   .setWidget(1,2,min)
   .setWidget(1,3,amPm)
   .setWidget(1,4,location)
   .setWidget(1,5,minuteTaker)

   hpanel.setWidget(2,5,submit)
   app.add(hpanel);//.add(warnException).add(warnExceptionMes);

  hpanelException.setWidget(1,1,warnException).setStyleAttribute("text-align", "right")
   .setWidget(1,2,warnExceptionMes)
  // .setWidget(1,2,nextSteps)
   app.add(hpanelException);
   return app;
     }
```

---

**EDIT** second version following your comment.
I simulated a server function that takes some time so you see all the steps. + I combined the warning as suggested. (demo code updated with version 2)

```
var templateIDToCopy = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
var folderIDtoCopyTo = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
var councilMembers = ['Unknown','Name 1','Name 2'];

function doGet(e) {
  var text= new Array();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var hpanel = app.createGrid(4, 6).setId('pannel');
  var hpanelException = app.createGrid(2,3).setId('hpanelException');
  var location = app.createTextBox().setName('location').setId("location").setWidth('200');
  var minuteTaker = app.createListBox().setName('minuteTaker').setId("minuteTaker").setWidth('200')
   for (var i = 0 ; i < councilMembers.length; i++) {
    minuteTaker.addItem(councilMembers.valueOf()[i]);
                    }

  var dateBox = app.createDateBox().setId('dateBox').setName('dateBox').setFireEventsForInvalid(false);
  var hour = app.createListBox(false).setId('hour').setName('hour')
//  var hour = app.createListBox(false).setId('hour').setName('hour')
  for(h=1;h<13;++h){hour.addItem(h)}
  var min = app.createListBox(false).setId('minute').setName('minute')
  .addItem('00').addItem('15').addItem('30').addItem('45'); 
  var amPm = app.createListBox(false).setId('am').setName('amPm')
  .addItem('AM').addItem('PM');  
  var dateTimeLabel = app.createLabel('',false).setId('dateTimeLabel');
  var submit = app.createButton('Create Minutes').setId('submit').setPixelSize(195, 65);
  var nextSteps = app.createAnchor('Please click here to see the minutes archive.', 'https://drive.google.com/xxxxxxxxxx/folderview?xxxxxxxxxx').setId('nextSteps').setVisible(false);

  var clearHandler = app.createClientHandler();

// Setup error message 
  var warnException =app.createImage('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/211279/clock_e0.gif').addClickHandler(clearHandler);
  var warnExceptionMes = app.createLabel('The date and Location are required. Please try again.').setStyleAttribute('font-weight', 'normal').setStyleAttribute('font-size','14px').addClickHandler(clearHandler);
  var warnPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().add(warnException).add(warnExceptionMes).setId('warning').setVisible(false);

  clearHandler.forTargets(warnPanel).setVisible(false);
// handlers
  var handler0 = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateLength(location, 0, 5)
  .forTargets(warnPanel).setVisible(true)

  var handler1 = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateNotMatches(dateBox, '2', 'g')
  .forTargets(warnPanel).setVisible(true)

  var handler2 = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateLength(location, 6, 100).validateMatches(dateBox, '2', 'g')
  .forEventSource().setText('Server Handler is running...').setEnabled(false)
  .forTargets(warnPanel).setVisible(false);

  var handlerS = app.createServerHandler('handlerFunction')
  .validateLength(location, 6, 100).validateMatches(dateBox, '2', 'g')
  .addCallbackElement(location).addCallbackElement(dateBox).addCallbackElement(hpanel);

  submit.addClickHandler(handler0).addClickHandler(handler1).addClickHandler(handler2).addClickHandler(handlerS);

  hpanel.setWidget(0,0,app.createLabel('Select Date'))
   .setWidget(0,1,app.createLabel('Hour'))
   .setWidget(0,2,app.createLabel('Minutes'))
   .setWidget(0,3,app.createLabel('AM/PM'))
   .setWidget(0,4,app.createLabel('Location'))
   .setWidget(0,5,app.createLabel('Minute Taker'))

  hpanel.setWidget(1,0,dateBox)
   .setWidget(1,1,hour)
   .setWidget(1,2,min)
   .setWidget(1,3,amPm)
   .setWidget(1,4,location)
   .setWidget(1,5,minuteTaker)

  hpanel.setWidget(2,5,submit)
  app.add(hpanel);

  hpanelException.setWidget(1,1,warnPanel).setStyleAttribute("text-align", "right")
  app.add(hpanelException);
  return app;
}


function handlerFunction(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  app.getElementById('submit').setText('SERVER HANDLER is DONE');
//  app.getElementById('warning').setVisible(false);// not necassary anymore, see clientHandler2
  return app;
    }
```

Comment: HUGE THANK YOU Serge. I really appreciate the help on this. This one really had me stumped.

Comment: So the one thing I still do not get is how to make the submit button do 2 things once the validations are met...  1 - Change the text on the button to "Building..." and disable the button.  I know I can do it down in my function handlerFunction(e) but I need to show it before that otherwise it will not update until all of the code is completed.

Comment: Also not sure how I can go about making the image and the text for the warning message as one? // Setup error message 
  var warnException =app.createImage('https://sites.google.com/xxxxxxxxxx/minutes/create-new-minutes/Opps.png').setId('warnException').setVisible(false).addClickHandler(clearHandler);
  var warnExceptionMes = app.createLabel('The date and Location are required. Please try again.').setStyleAttribute('font-weight', 'normal').setStyleAttribute('font-size','14px').setVisible(false).addClickHandler(clearHandler);

Comment: Thanks for unaccepting... always a pleasure. I answered your question and provided an example + code if you change the question in between... I don't follow. sorry

Comment: Sorry about that, did it by mistake. Thought I hit the up arrow. New to the site. I do appreciate the aid.

Comment: Good to know , thanks. What exactly are you wanting to do ?  Set the text on the button as it is now but in a client handler instead?

Comment: Your welcome. I just want to disable the button and change the text to "Building..." once all the validation has passed so that the user knows that it is busy doing work in the background. I have been able to do this within the function handlerFunction(e) however by the time that does the return app all the work is done. Trying to figure out where setting that text and disabling the button takes place right after successful validation. Also, I liked your suggestion about making the error text and image one Widget however I have been unable to determine a method of combining them.

Comment: OK, got it... give me Max an hour and I'll be back... just eating now :-)

Comment: No rush, enjoy your lunch! And again, thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Thank you! Highly appreciated. I will try it out shortly. I learn best by example so this is a huge help to me. Thanks again.